# Meaning of a/b/c/d style of formula notation in Fortran

Tags: formula

If a formula is written as A/B/C/D, I couldn't understand what is the mathematical structure.

In mathematics, if I write A/B/C it means A*C / B, is it the same here too?

Comment: `A/B/C` it means `A*C/B` - what? `16/2/2` != `16*2/2`, it's actually `16/(2*2)`.

Comment: He is talking about fractions A/B/C is: a/1 * c/b (inverted) ! Is that right?

Comment: I apologize, I should have added brackets, lets say I've (A/B), and if somebody does (A/B)/C then it's A/(B*C), 

if it's A/(B/C), then it's (A*C)/B, in FORTRAN, I couldn't make sense of what it means by A/B/C/D etc...

It's not a fraction, it's a formula that's written like that in the code.

Answer (score 0):

I query that in mathematics "A/B/C it means A*C / B" because the operator precedence order is a matter of convention and in mathematics the convention I am familiar with is to avoid ambiguity in such cases. So where the result of `A*C / B` is intended it would be written `A/(B/C)`, as:

[image: Formula example]

or in some other way that avoids ambiguity.

Say A is `100`, B `5` and C is `2`:

`A*C / B` returns `40`.

`A/(B/C)` returns `40`.

But in Fortran operators of equal order and evaluated left-to-right, eg from *Fortran 95* by M Counihan:

[image: Fortan]

So `A/B/C` is evaluated as `(A/B)/C`, ie `10`. This is conventional in computing with Excel and Google Spreadsheets for example returning `10` from:

```
=A1/B1/C1
```

Introduce D as say `4` and the result of A/B/C/D is `2.5`.